# Django & Jquery: How do you override chosen values selected in a FilteredSelectMultiple?

Tags: jquery, python, django

I'm making a work order. In a work order, you can choose set of tools that you'll use.

```
class WorkOrder( models.Model ):
    job_type_choices = ( 
                 ( '1', 'Mechanical' ), 
                 ( '2', 'Electrical' ), 
                 ( '3', 'Instrumentation' ), 
                 )

   tools = models.ManyToManyField( Equipment, related_name='tools', blank=True, null=True )
   job_type = models.CharField( max_length=45, choices=job_type_choices )
```

Now, a user can create a work order template.

```
class WorkOrderTemplate( models.Model ):
    job_type_choices = ( 
                 ( '1', 'Mechanical' ), 
                 ( '2', 'Electrical' ), 
                 ( '3', 'Instrumentation' ), 
                 )

    tools = models.ManyToManyField( Equipment ) #set all the default tools here
    job_type = models.CharField( max_length=45, choices=job_type_choices )
```

Everytime you change the value of the job_type, which is a dropdown list, you will load all the tools that you selected in the work order template with the same job_type you've chosen.

The widget I'm using FilteredMultipleChoice widget:

```
tools = ModelMultipleChoiceField( 
    queryset=Equipment.objects.all(),  
    widget=widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple( "Tools", is_stacked=False ), 
    required=False )
```

I know how to override the value of a simple textinput, but I have no idea how to override chosen values in this case. For that, I used jquery.

Thanks in advance :)